# Does Oracle Weblogic 11g has Enterprise Edition?

Tags: weblogic11g, osb

I need Weblogic server 11g version in Enterprise Edition and if its exists does OEPE/OSB is included in that?

I got to know that Weblogic 10.3.4 has OEPE included in that, but not sure whether it is in Enterprise Edition

Answer (score 0):

I am using the Oracle Weblogic server Versione WebLogic Server: 10.3.6.0 (11g). To be integrated in Eclipse (I am using Eclipse Oxygen 3a), I followed below steps -

- Install Oracle Weblogic Server Tools from Eclipse Market Place.
  OR
- Server View-->Add New Server-->Oracle--> Oracle Weblogic Server Tools.

Please try eclipse photon and you can find the instructions on below URL -

https://www.oracle.com/tools/downloads/oepe-v12219-downloads.html

Comment: Is there any other Weblogic version in which consists OEPE as one of its product and also it should be Enterprise edition?

Comment: Please see if this helps you. https://www.oracle.com/tools/downloads/oepe-v12219-downloads.html